# TV-Shaped CSS Figure delimiting image

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I can't seem to figure how to accomplish the following.

I have this shape:

[image: CSS Shape]

This is the desired outcome:

[image: Desired]

However, when I apply the overflow to the child div this happens:

[image: Happens]

Or this when the overflow is in the parent div

[image]

I have tried splitting the CSS into more divs and then trying to overlap them and all these attempts have been failures.

The HTML and CSS are the following

**CSS:**

```
#tvshape {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 20px 10px;
 background: #0809fe;
 border-radius: 50% / 10%;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: .1em;
}

#tvshape:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 bottom: 10%;
 right: -5%;
 left: -5%;
 background: inherit;
 border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}

#tvshape img {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

**HTML** (Nothing special)**:**

```
<div id="tvshape">
    <img src="http://wallpaperpanda.com/wallpapers/pbc/RER/pbcRERyTy.jpg">
</div>
```

And [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/98bxT/) is the JSFiddle and the CSS and HTML.

How could I accomplish so ?

Guidance will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I required the image to be an element of it's own, `background:url()` it's not what I'm looking for.

**EDIT #2**: This was one of the solutions given, the figures are not the same ones, the rounded left and right sides dissapear.

[image: notequal]

**Thank you.**

Comment: Tried this with another image : http://jsfiddle.net/98bxT/7/

Comment: @Joel Hernandez The next fiddle looks good - does it answer your question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could come up with two options, though one involves leaving out the `image`-element, and the second uses jQuery... (I honestly don't think it's possible to do with the `image`-element...sorry.)

**Option 1)**

Since the image URL has to be in the HTML code, adjust the code like this:

```
<div id="tvshape" style="background-image: url(http://wallpaperpanda.com/wallpapers/pbc/RER/pbcRERyTy.jpg);"></div>
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
#tvshape {
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/cqPR8/

**Option 2)**

Basically the same as Option 1, except I "cheated" by leaving the HTML code as it was, i.e.

```
<div id="tvshape">
    <img src="http://wallpaperpanda.com/wallpapers/pbc/RER/pbcRERyTy.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Add some jQuery so that the HTML ends up looking like Option 1:

```
var tvbackground = $('#tvshape img').attr('src');
$('#tvshape').css('background-image', 'url(' + tvbackground + ')');
```

Then finally hide the `image`-tag with CSS:

```
#tvshape img {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/4WFL5/

Answer (score 0):

I just included this code in your css

```
#tvshape{ background:url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Y1fFfKjiX2g/S_gMwLeGtjI/AAAAAAAALlE/vdX0ttHeEjg/s1600/CLOUDS2.jpg')center no-repeat; }
```

The image used is taken randomly just for example purposes. Is this desired version you want?

JSFiddle : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/98bxT/7/)

Comment: I'm seeing quite a few of these.  It seems like a homework assignment.

Comment: I did thought about it but I require the image to be handled as an object in the DOM. I'm sorry about not specifiying it.

Comment: I am not understanding? You want a 2nd image other than blue one on top of it?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I require for the image to be "inside" the CSS figure without overpassing it's boundaries and for this to work , the figure being a div and the "<img>" inside of it.